# UndoManager's canUndo property not updating in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, nsundomanager

Why does the `@Environment` `UndoManager` not update its `canUndo` property when it has actions in its stack? I have a view that has a child that can utilize the un/redo functionality, but for some reason I can't disable the undo button based on the manager.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager: UndoManager?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Undo") { ... }
            .disabled(!self.undoManager!.canUndo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UndoManager.canUndo` is not KVO compliant, so use some notification publisher to track state, like below

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
    @State private var canUndo = false

    // consider also other similar notifications
    private let undoObserver = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSUndoManagerDidCloseUndoGroup)

    var body: some View {
        Button("Undo") { }
            .disabled(!canUndo)
            .onReceive(undoObserver) { _ in
                self.canUndo = self.undoManager!.canUndo
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This mostly works. It seems that the `undoManager` never actually closes the group. Even when all actions have been undone, it still triggers the did close notification and returns true for `canUndo`. But this notification allowed for me to keep track of undoable actions in some other state variables.

Comment: I found this works better with [ ***private let undoObserver = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSUndoManagerCheckpoint)*** ] You're then able to get the canUndo and canRedo states correctly

Comment: @PaulOllivier if you query canRedo on receive NSUndoManagerCheckpoint this will cause an infinite loop, as canRedo fires the checkpoint notification: "Posted whenever an NSUndoManager object opens or closes an undo group (except when it opens a top-level group) and when checking the redo stack in canRedo."

Comment: @OliverD Thanks I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `canRedo` I tried multiple things, and what I ended up with is this - so observing `viewModel` (or `document` or any other undo-supporting data source) and updating `canUndo`/`canRedo` in reaction to it's change:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    @Environment(\.undoManager) private var undoManger: UndoManager!
    @State private var canUndo = false
    @State private var canRedo = false
    
    var body: some View {
        RootView()
            .onReceive(viewModel.objectWillChange) { _ in
                canUndo = undoManger.canUndo
                canRedo = undoManger.canRedo
            }

        if canUndo {
            Button(
                action: { undoManger?.undo() },
                label: { Text("Undo") }
            )
        }
        if canRedo {
            Button(
                action: { undoManger?.redo() },
                label: { Text("Redo") }
            )
        }
        ...
```

I also wrapped it in a [standalone button](https://gist.github.com/Czajnikowski/1a35463217777af93e7d7959a44d1514) (without overgeneralizing the implementation above my own needs) that eliminates the boilerplate from my view and keeps complexity more private so it ends up like this for me:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
       RootView()
       UndoManagerActionButton(
           .undo,
           willChangePublisher: viewModel.objectWillChange
       )
       UndoManagerActionButton(
           .redo,
           willChangePublisher: viewModel.objectWillChange
       )
       ...
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "so observing viewModel (or document or any other undo-supporting data source)" as your code doesn't show what your ViewModel is. Anything you can point me to explain this?